# How do I hide an Outlook JS Add-In for OWA, but not for other applications (desktop outlook, Office365)?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there an option in the manifest.xml to stop the Add-In from appearing in the OWA app ?
It appears that FormSettings is a mandatory field, and at least one Form is required.

There are some functional parity issues with OWA (e.g. UI-less action, TaskPane for EditItems) that push us to forego having it there.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible currently.  You can detect what kind of client is being used, but only when the app is opened.  There is a user-voice feature request related to specifying whether an app is OWA-only or Outlook-only: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5129669-allow-mail-apps-to-be-owa-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature : "showing add-in on specific platform"
, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

There are no options currently. You may post your feedback or request on the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=208903) page.